# Kohana minion не находит класс

Tags: php, kohana

Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
При запуске скрипта из консоли через minion (kohana framework) он не может найти класс

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Model\Task...' not found in .... on line 73

Весь "прикол" в том, что на локальном сервере все ок (frdora 21) а на удаленном сервере проблемы (ubuntu 14.04)

вызываю скрипт из консоли след образом

```
./modules/minion/minion --task=taskName
```

Comment: может быть дело в переменной окружения `$PATH`?

Comment: А что с ней может быть не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему.
Проблема была в том, что в ubuntu для CLI отдельный конфиг, и в нем короткие теги (short_tags) были выключены, а в файле был именно short_tag (< ?).
После включения коротких тегов все заработало.